# CSS animte background image issue in html5

Tags: css, html, animation

**Html5:**

```
        <div id="slideshow">
        <div id='animate-area'>
        </div>
        </div>
```

**Css:**

```
body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #slideshow {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 145px;
    }
    #animate-area { 
        height: 100%;
        width: 2538px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        background-image: url('../img/banner.png');
        animation: animatedBackground 40s 5s linear infinite;
        -ms-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
        -moz-animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
        -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 30s linear infinite;
    }
    /* Put your css in here */
    @keyframes animatedBackground {
        from { left: 0; }
        to { left: -1269px; }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
        from { left: 0; }
        to { left: -1269px; }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes animatedBackground {
        from { left: 0; }
        to { left: -1269px; }
    }
```

**JSfiddle:**

```
jsfiddle.net/cz04c4nx/1
```

Using this image, I need show like, http://jsfiddle.net/5pVr4/6/.  I tried, but for my particular image `url('../img/banner.png')` when run in localhost, can't able to get.

Comment: are you sure about the relative path u r providing. I feel it is more of a issue with path. can u provide your project folder structure

Comment: can anybody help me please?

Comment: in your non-prefixed `animation`, there is a `5s` delay, while the prefixed ones have none. Try removing that.

Comment: @jacelysh: I removed, but nothing change.

Comment: Finally this is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cz04c4nx/1/, hear how to remove, black space?

Comment: But your image itself has the black space in it. You can try either removing it using software like Photoshop, OR add this to your `#animate-area` rules: `background-position: center center;
    background-size: auto 170%;` Please note that the `170%` is relative only to the fiddle you provided, you may change it depending on the actual size in your website

Comment: no, my original image is, different from displayed in web page.. im my original image, noo black space, and height of image is high.

Comment: @jacelysh: from your comments, there is display like show changes, for every roation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i solved your problem. You can use this code and it may be help you.I edited that code which you can make similar animate background image.

**CSS Code:**

```
@-webkit-keyframes MOVE-BG {
from {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
}
to { 
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-550px);
}
}

#content {
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: white;   
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.bg{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: -550px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: url(http://s30.postimg.org/qnju89rkx/banner.png) 0% 0% repeat;
    z-index: -1;

    -webkit-animation-name: MOVE-BG;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

**[Live Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kalusingh/5pVr4/179/)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. but still i didn't get what i want.